# Unable to install SLATE via PIP

Tags: python, pip, slate

I'm getting the following error when I try to install slate using `pip install slate`:

```
C:\Users\co_46>pip install slate
Collecting slate
  Using cached slate-0.3.zip (20 kB)
Collecting distribute
  Using cached distribute-0.7.3.zip (145 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\co_46\anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\co_46\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qq4oek2a\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\co_46\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qq4oek2a\\distribute\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\co_46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-2veaa5ur'
         cwd: C:\Users\co_46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qq4oek2a\distribute\
    Complete output (15 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\co_46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qq4oek2a\distribute\setuptools\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
        from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
      File "C:\Users\co_46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qq4oek2a\distribute\setuptools\extension.py", line 5, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
      File "C:\Users\co_46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qq4oek2a\distribute\setuptools\dist.py", line 7, in <module>
        from setuptools.command.install import install
      File "C:\Users\co_46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qq4oek2a\distribute\setuptools\command\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from setuptools.command import install_scripts
      File "C:\Users\co_46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qq4oek2a\distribute\setuptools\command\install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
      File "C:\Users\co_46\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qq4oek2a\distribute\pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
        register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
    AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I am using Python 3.9.1 on a Windows 10 Machine. I have tried to update GEVENT after doing some researching and finding out that could be problem but that continues to fail.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: The package is very old and doesn't look like it supports Python3. You might be able to find a fork that supports your Python version, https://pypi.org/project/slate3k/ is an option although it also has not been updated in a while

Answer (score 0):

Using the full repo URL did the trick for me:

```
pip install https://github.com/timClicks/slate/archive/master.zip
```